# How do i completly remove an Nvidia driver by hand?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I use a GF108M [GeForce GT 620M/630M/635M/640M LE] and (want to) use the nvidia-driver-390. However if i install this driver (via package manager) i get an error from nvidia-smi, complaining about a version missmatch (`API mismatch: the client has the version 470.86, but this kernel module has the version 390.157.`). This is the version from a nvidia driver thats seems to be partly somehow installed.

If i use the installer from nvidia (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.157.run) i do not get this problem, but i would prefer to use the package manager version. If i uninstall this driver and reinstall the package manager version, then the problem reappears.

I also tried to install and uninstall the expected version (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.86.run), but this one ofcourse does not support my graphics card, so the installation does not complete and i cant uninstall whatever is causing this version missmatch.

**My current best lead:** How/Where can i find the file that the NVRM API gets its client version? Or better: how can i cleant these remains of the wrong driver?

**What i have tried:**

- purge and reinstall packages
- install and uninstall 390 (the correct one) and 470 (the problem one) Nvidia drivers from runfiles
- Regenerate Kernel images
- Reinstall Kernels

**What i have**
Ubuntu 22.04 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu
GeForce GT 630M
With the package manager driver:
NVIDIA System Management Interface -- v390.157
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.157  Wed Oct 12 09:19:07 UTC 2022
GCC version:
$ cat /sys/module/nvidia/version
390.157
$ modinfo nvidia | grep version
version:        390.157
srcversion:     969136205C7AF53C6F7D4AE
vermagic:       5.15.0-56-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
$ sudo dmesg
[  348.574962] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 470.86, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 390.157.  Please
NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
NVRM: components have the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, for anyone interested:
after a purge i used `find /usr/lib -iname "*nvidia*"` and found a bunch of files with 470.86 in their name.
I used `sudo find /usr/lib -iname "*nvidia*470\.86" -delete` to delete them and `sudo find /usr/lib -iname "*nvidia*\.ko" -delete` to delete other nvidia files that sould not be there, leaving only things like NvidiaDetector.
Reinstall the correct driver & reboot and not it works